# I don't understand the hint given when proving the limit of a log function

Tags: limits, logarithms

The question is to prove the following limit, $n \to \infty $

$$
\frac{n}{t} \ln({1 + \frac{t}{n}}) \to 1
$$

I could do this using something like L'Hôpital's rule but the hint is "Use the differentiability of log at 1 to show that for each t"

I don't know how to prove it using the hint. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: What is the limit of $\frac{t}{n}$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$ ? The differentiability of $\log$ at $1$ implies that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the limit in question is equivalent to
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)}{\frac{t}{n}}. 
$$
Suppose we fixed a value of $t$, then we note that $\frac{t}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. By a change of variables $h = \frac{t}{n}$, we rewrite the limit as
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+h\right)}{h}. 
$$
Now use the hint. (Can you think of this limit as the derivative of something somewhere?) Note that this limit works for every fixed value of $t$, so this should work for every $t$, and whenever $n\to\infty$.

**Edit**:

The expression above is exactly the derivative of the natural log function at $x = 1$. Indeed, by definition, the derivative is given by
\begin{align*}
[\ln(x)]'= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln (x+h)-\ln(x)}{(x+h)-x},
\end{align*}
then when evaluated at $x = 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
[\ln(x)]'\mid_{x = 1}&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+h)-\ln(1)}{(1+h)-1}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+h)}{h}
\end{align*}
Also note that the value of this limit should be well-known...

Comment: No sorry, I'm struggling to see it

Comment: @GodelEscher Just edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way, note that as $n \to \infty,$ we have $r:=n/t\to \infty,$ so the limit is the same as

$$\lim_{r \to\infty }r\ln (1+1/r)=\ln \lim_{r \to\infty }(1+1/r)^r=\ln e =1, $$

where the first equality is by limit and log properties, and the second equality is by the limit definition of $e$.